# Problems (delays) with window messages on Windows (C++)

Tags: c++, windows, window-messages

There is a problem in my application. After a long system downtime or sleep window messages come with a delay of a few seconds! Once the window receives this message all further message proceed normally again.
I created a method invoked manually and throwing window message like this:

```
PostMessage(this->Handle,MY_HOT_KEY,HotKeyMessage::hkmSomeKey,0);
```

Nothing has changed. It seems all the same problem with receiving Messages, not sending it. Who knows what it can be connected with?

*(Tested on systems from Windows XP to Windows 8.1. Created using C++ Builder. Compiled in x86 applicaion)*

Answer (score 3):

Windows is not a Real Time Operating System (RTOS). Delays like this are normal, especially when the system is busy resuming from sleep.

Comment: Very sorrowfully if you're right... And what about the case of a long system downtime?